# How can I find what is using all of the server memory and record a log of it for analysis afterwards?

Tags: memory, windows-server-2016, memory-usage

I am running Windows 2016 Server on IBM Cloud.
Today the server crashed as in it became unresponsive and the websites stopped responding as well as the Microsoft SQL Database server instance.

Normally the CPU usage and the RAM usage is pretty good.
I am attaching screenshots for the previous week.

Now, from task manager it showed 99% RAM usage before we had to restart the server. However, it is obvious that there was something else not shown that was using all of the memory.

This crash happened while me as the sole computer engineer was sleeping. After I get the server had already been rebooted, and then the reports of the 30 minutes of downtime came to me.

I want to figure out what started using all the memory. I have searched all the logs I can find for the time period but I can't find anything that has been helpful. Is there any tips to finding out the culprit? Is there a way to record and make a log of the processes running and how much Memory they are using? (so I can come and check to see what process used all the memory)

Task manager during crash:
[image: Task manager during crash]

7 days of CPU usage:
[image: 7 days of CPU usage]

7 days of memory usage:
[image: 7 days of memory usage]

Task manager normal usage:
[image: Task manager normal usage]

Comment: Nope, impossioble with the data you provided and likely not possible with the data you did collect. You do not by chance run a professional performance analysis tool that does collect data in the backround and orgot to tell us? You did limit SQL Server and IIS process memory? No way without data to know what went wrong, and you did not collect data. Last chance is checking the sql server logs for something off.

Comment: I agree. After this happened I put a limit on Microsoft SQL Server Memory to about 80%. I have not limited IIS process memory. My main question now is how do I collect the data. What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: I was able to get another screenshot showing the issue: https://ibb.co/G2MtTSS